# hardware wallet

Tags: wallet, security

With all the hacking of personal computers, ledger, and t-mobile; what is the safest way to store ADA? I have been hacked through ledger live through a google add-on. Is Yori with ledger safe?

thanks,
totally paranoid

Comment: Could you explain how you were hacked in Ledger Live? What Google add-on? What did the hack do? Also, you’ll get better responses if you edit your title and ask a meaningful question, rather than just having “hardware wallet”. Have a look at the titles of other questions as examples.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Ledger live doesn't have a google add-on, you were only scammed.  There isn't a way to get hacked with ledger live unless you accept a transaction. I've been using Ledger since 2017 it works as long as you pay attention to what transaction you're accepting on your ledger device.

Those people who got hacked via a sim swap didn't understand basic cyber security.
First of all, you don't use SMS as 2nd step authentication, use Google Authenticator or the many vendors with a similar app.

You do not leave your bag holding on an exchange PERIOD!. Mt.Gox is a primary example of why and this continues today for those who don't spend the time to learn this lesson.

IF you have over 100k in crypto and don't have a ledger or [trezor](https://trezor.io/) and a [Cryptotag](https://cryptotag.io/?gclid=CjwKCAjw95yJBhAgEiwAmRrutKLy1bazkPQXMzxccvdMPWnZzEpxzWJbdqdEqVKHdlYbluZ1hSiQbBoC_XYQAvD_BwE) or [blockplate](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.blockplate.com/&sa=D&ust=1630095207714270&usg=AOvVaw2x2lDGKk_3RlX6nGibE7y6&hl=en), it's only a matter of time before you lose it all.

My ADA is safe with only $230 invested in hardware because I spent extra to get titanium plates to protect my seed phrase sold by Cryptotag. Heed these warnings or get featured in the next "I got hacked from coinbase and I'm mad" article.

also, Charles does not give away free ADA. NEVER!!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many users I have a slightly different than mainstream view on Trezor & Ledger.

Avoid both. Ledgers internal servers where hacked and all of their customer information was released to the world. Also there was a [Shopify leak](https://cryptopotato.com/ledger-admits-users-data-leaked-amid-the-shopify-incident-in-april-june-2020/) as well. I know two stake pool operators who's info was released and they are constantly being sent spoofed emails and one of them fell for one.

[Trezor link](https://hackaday.com/2021/02/04/hacking-hardware-bitcoin-wallets-extracting-the-cryptographic-seed-from-a-trezor/)

Hacking users is far easier than hacking secure systems. All they would have to do to is get you to click on something in an email and they can trace that IP to your physical location through your ISP.

For any large sum wallet keep it on paper (Titanium? Need to enter an address to have it shipped).

Create the wallet(3 copies of the seed stored in different locations), add funds, delegate to OTG pool(or some other pool..) Then delete the wallet off the computer. It will earn rewards and can be restored when needed.

If you want a wallet for interacting with the blockchain like buying/trading NFT's create a second smaller wallet with [Nami](https://namiwallet.io/). Nami is single address wallet while Yoroi is multi address so create a new wallet in Nami and add funds to it. Brave browser is nice.

It would also be best to get an open source privacy respecting operating system and encrypt your dns traffic. [elementary.io](https://elementary.io/) for example is an Ubuntu based OS and secure.

Full paranoid is an old Thinkpad with encrypted Libreboot with Trisquel.

Intel & AMD have backdoors so it depends who you think your adversaries are.

https://hackaday.com/2020/06/16/disable-intels-backdoor-on-modern-hardware/
https://www.flashedtech.com/

Peace & Freedom!

Comment: Ledgers' internal servers don't affect the Ledger devices. I was in that hack myself, My crypto was fine the whole time and since I know what a phishing email is like and scam calls, I managed just fine. Also Ledgers use secure element chips. 

Also, SPOs should know better about scams and proper key management, it's not acceptable to be in that position of power in the network and to be vulnerable to an email scam.